# Redirect output from terminal to GUI instead

Tags: user-interface, pyqt, pyqt6

I finally got my GUI and I'd say all its content/elements working. Hooray (btw, thanks to all contributions, here!).
Now I am about to polish multiple things and one thing is the following: At the moment there is quite a lot that is simply printed within the terminal (I'm starting the GUI also via the terminal atm but I wanna' change it to a stand-alone .exe soon). Thus, I would like to know whether there is a convenient GUI element already, something like a widget or similar, which simply re-directs the output send to the terminal instead to a window inside the GUI, or so?

I've seen [How can I display terminal output to a text box in PyQt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57563047/how-can-i-display-terminal-output-to-a-text-box-in-pyqt) but can't figure out the specific purpose of the functions, widgets and so on there as I'm still not that familiar with pyqt.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to redirect output from the terminal. It also depends on where this information being printed to the terminal is coming from, is it coming from another program? Is it coming from the logic inside the PyQt program? If you could clarify this it would be helpful.

If the information is coming from inside your PyQt program, then you need to connect the result you want to print to the GUI component that will print on the screen for the end user to see. To that I say, use [Signals][1].

Suppose the information that is being printed on the terminal is coming from another program. In that case, as far as I know, you can only grab the output if the output is coming from a program being executed by your python application, like this using subprocess:

```py
from subprocess import run

CPP_FILE = "out.cpp"
CXX = "g++"

run([CXX, CPP_FILE], capture_output=True, text=True)
result = run(["./a.out"], capture_output=True, text=True)
```

then you would grab the variable `result` and send it to the GUI component to exhibit. I hope that it was helpful.
[1]: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html